# Is there another option to doing same functionality of stored procedure in SQLite?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, stored-procedures

We have a huge SQL Server database and it has some stored procedures for calculation. We also have an mobile app using the same database.

Now we want to use the mobile app offline. So we need use SQLite database. As you know stored procedures don't work in SQLite.. (we also don't want to calculate in code which is made by stored procedures in the SQL Server database)

**My question is**: is it possible make this mobile app under these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an embedded database, and is designed to be used together with a 'real' programming language.

Just use a non-stored procedure in your app:

```java
void MyLittleProcedure() {
    db.exeSQL("SELECT this ...");
    db.exeSQL("UPDATE that ...");
}
```